# Combining probabilities from different CNN models

Tags: classification, conv-neural-network, combinations, probability

Let's say I have 2 images of a car, but one is generated from the camera and the other is a depth image generated from Lidar pointcloud transformation.

I used the same CNN model on both image to predict the class (output is a softmax, as there is other classes in my dataset : pedestrian, van, truck, cyclist, etc.

How can I combine the two probabilities vector in order to predict the class by taking into account both predictions?

I used method like average, maximum, minimum, naive product apply to each score for each class, but don't know if it work.

Thanks you in advance

EDIT :

Following this article : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327744903_Multimodal_CNN_Pedestrian_Classification_a_Study_on_Combining_LIDAR_and_Camera_Data

We can see that they use maximum or minimum rule to combine the outpout of classifiers. So dit it work for multiclass problem?

[image]

Comment: It's important to understand that the CNN outputs are **not** probabilities. A probability is defined by statistics, and has well-defined mathematical properties. For instance, for independent events you can multiply probabilities. At least with softmax, the outputs sum to 100%, but that's only because softmax scales the individual values. Of course, your two softmax functions here apply their own, unrelated scalings. Since this is pseudo-statistics, you could just add or multiply the pre-softmax values per class instead, and then softmax the results. It will still look like a probability.

Comment: Yes it is a abuse of langage, I know that it is not a probability but we modelize it as it is the probability that the image belong to the class. Why do you mean by softmax the results? ie to concatenate before softmax layer ?

Comment: With "softmax the results", I mean apply a softmax activation function to the outcome of the last matrix multiplication. The matrix multiplication gives you a vector in ℝn , not something which looks like a probability distribution. That's why you apply softmax there. But if you need to combine the results, why not postpone the softmax?

Comment: Do you know how wan I combine the scores using classification techniques like svm? As we can see on this image that came from tue article : !(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/28/4/1562847711-5ccb5845-c6bf-462a-b78c-b5bb9b08c8c1.png)

Comment: That's easy. When training the SVM, you take the two CNN's as given (i.e. you just use them for inference). The SVM is simple, with just the CNN outputs as input and one output. You just treat the CNN's as a preprocessing step on the input.

Comment: You mean I don’t use softmax at the last layer? I don’t understand how can I train the svm, they (and you) are talking about train with ouput scores, but you mean the output scores that derived from each unimomal cnn on the testing set? For exemple imagine first cnn give  A=p_1a, p_2a, p_3a according to classifier A and B=p_1b, p_2b, p_3b according to classifier B. Vectors A and B becomes train samples for the svm? What are positive and negative samples? Because here we have 3 classes

Comment: Doesn't make a difference whether you use a softmax, if there's an SVM behind the  CNN's. The SVM will learn either way. As for learning, the SVM uses the exact same classes as the two CNN's. And yes, a SVM is probably not the best choice for a second-stage classifier whn you have multiple labels.

Comment: Is what I say is correct? Imagine I just have two class . The training samples for the svm are the output scores of the different cnn for  each sample of my test set ? Seems weird to me.

Comment: It's not that weird. The SVM is learning when to trust which CNN, and to what degree.

Comment: So to resume :                                                                       - I apply the different CNN on the test set.             - I take all the output scores Li (i=1..3) as training samples for the  svm.                                 -I predict the class by applying svm model on my test set     (As I have multi class, maybe I can use kNN or one vs all svm)

Comment: training samples = score vectors, and real class are ? Class of the test set?

Comment: Correct. The ground truth doesn't change by your choice of models.

Comment: But why in the artcile it is written "Li from the training set"? Beacause the confidence scores comes when we evaluate on the test set

Comment: Well, since the SVM is a form of machine learning, you need to split your data (the usual train/validation/test split). That split can follow the earlier split used to train the CNN's, or it can be a different split. In a paper like this, the authors should document what they did, but it's often not critical.

Comment: I know about the split, which I don't understand is How to train the SVM once I have the output scores on the test set for each unimodal CNN. Are the steps should be the following? : 1) Train each CNN on the training set (I have a train set containing images from camera, train set containing images obtained from projected lidar pointcloud) 2) Apply each model on the test set (same architecture) and get the output scores. 3) This output scores becomes training sample of my SVM, ex X = [0.3,0.7] and target is the true class of the sample from the test set (ex 1).

Comment: Then I train the SVM and for predict the class I apply the svm model on the test set ? What is weird to me is to train a model using predictions on test set.. don't know If I am clear.

Comment: Are your camera and lidar training sets matched? Because I had pretty much assumed that part.

Comment: Here is a exemple of camera images from the camera 's train set; !(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/1/1563206521-car101c.png)  and the  associated lidar image from the lidar's train set :!(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/29/1/1563206531-car101d.png). The lidar image is obtained by projecting the lidar pointcloud into the camera image plane; so the same object is represented in both training set

Comment: The thing is that after the steps described, thé if I use my Svm model for the test set; output scores of cnn on the test set will be part of training samples of the svm and it is not good. So what do they mean by using the confidence score from the training set for training svm?

Comment: @MSalters, do you find solution to my problem?

Answer (score 2):

As per MSalter's comment, the softmax output isn't a true probability vector. But if we choose to regard it as such, we can simply take the average of each prediction. This is equivalent to having two persons each classify a random sample of objects from a big pool of objects and assuming they both counted an equal amount, estimate the distribution of objects in the big pool by combining their observations. The sum of the 'probabilities' of the classes will still equal 1.

Comment: so taking for exemple the maximum score for each class from the different scores vector and then take the max probability for the prediction will not work?

Comment: @Doxcos44: The problem with taking the maximums of the two softmax vectors is that the "probabilities" no longer add up to 100%, which defeats the purpose of the softmax.

Comment: Yes, but if you take the max and put that through a softmax again, it will be a probability vector once more (i.e. sum to 1). However, there is no obvious reason that this (or averaging) should represent actual probabilities. But if it works...

Comment: Don't know if  you see it, but in this article they use maximum method : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327744903_Multimodal_CNN_Pedestrian_Classification_a_Study_on_Combining_LIDAR_and_Camera_Data. But it is binary classsification..

Comment: I don't really understand how to use softmax for two score vectors

Comment: Let us say you have three classes with 'probabilities' p_1a, p_2a, p_3a according to classifier A and p_1b, p_2b, p_3b according to classifier B. If you take the max of each, you may end up with p_1a, p_2b, p_3b, which may not sum to 1. So you take the softmax: p_1 = e^(-p_1a) / [e^(-p_1a) + e^(-p_2b) + e^(-p_3b)], and likewise for 2 and 3. Then p_1 + p_2 + p_3 = 1.

Comment: ok thanks, I didn't read correctly! There is no minus in softmax function no?

Comment: No, you're right, I had my head in a different formula.

Comment: I have better accuracy using combination methods rather than using just one type of images ! great !

Comment: Do you know how wan I combine the scores using classification techniques like svm? As we can see on this image that came from tue article : !(https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/28/4/1562847711-5ccb5845-c6bf-462a-b78c-b5bb9b08c8c1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Following this article : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327744903_Multimodal_CNN_Pedestrian_Classification_a_Study_on_Combining_LIDAR_and_Camera_Data

We can see that they use maximum or minimum rule to combine the outpout of classifiers. So dit it work for multiclass problem?

[image]